# Is this possible to merge laravel and wordpress together?

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, frameworks, content-management-system

I am wondering that laravel is best for query builder for MySQL and various field in web development. It is managed by controller which has a effective control for backend logic. But Wordpress is best for fronted and blog (Custom functionality is possible but not as laravel). It has many drag and drop tools to build frontend design. Can I use laravel api as WordPress backend?

Comment: you cant compare a framework with a CMS. Compare laravel Nova to wordpress or Winter CMS to wordpress wich both are based on laravel frameword. in any case, your question is opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel and WordPress really have pretty different opinions about database structure and interface. What you might consider is building an API in Laravel and accessing it via a plugin in WordPress. You'd have two independent websites but they could work together.